# Making an infinite box without compositor and without cycles?

Tags: shaders, transparency, shader-nodes

I'm trying to do something like this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nbgrcX8i588&list=PLSh-b4qMjucsIsfsV2ItRFpAUSkgb0WKa&index=20&t=74s

The only differences are that I need to have objects around the window still visible and I need to hide objects that are behind the window when looking through the window

[image]

I want the grid to only be visible while looking through the opening in the box while also keeping the blue objects outside the box visible.
I need something like a holdout shader on the inside of the box except it needs to be able to let certain objects through. I also need something that will hide the grid except when you look through a certain space or window. Ideally I wouldn't want to use the compositor or cycles.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.